# PHP / JavaScript Progress bar

Tags: javascript, php

I have a progress bar that looks [LIKE THIS](https://gyazo.com/565d099ec5f9ea7a9ae38736ecc72973)

I also have a table for each user called time (which is a future expirey date. For example 1 day ahead, 1 week ahead... anything bigger than now).

I have made it so it calculates how many days, hours and minutes they have left until the time has been reached using the following code :

```
  <?php
    foreach($users as $user) {
      $now = new DateTime();
      $clientTime_console = $user[11]; $future_date_console = new DateTime($clientTime_console); $interval_console = $future_date_console->diff($now);
    }
  ?>
```

Then I call this by using :

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) { echo $user[11] != '' ? $interval_console->format("<b>%a</b>d <b>%h</b>h <b>%i</b>m") : 'Not set'; } ?>
```

That works.

But then my progress bar. 
I want 100% to be the amount of time they originally were given and then for the progress bar to go down as their days pass.

I'm not sure how I would do this.

If I need another table or anything, could anyone let me know ?

Note that I add users or update users using my backend so I could possibly make a table called `last-time-given` and then update it when I either add or update a users time.

My progress bar is this :

```
<div class="bar -info" style="width: 80%;"></div>
```

As you can see, it's done by the width so I would need to put in the style, a percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Have something like that:

```
    <div class="bar -info" style="width: 
 <?php echo (strval($future_date_console->diff($now).s / $now->diff($total_time_allow).s)+"%");?>
    ;"></div>
```

If think you can adapt it to your need

Comment: I made a definition for `$total_time_allow` which is `$total_time_allow   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+7 day"));` and it still doesn't show the bar.

Comment: Does the PHP return a correct value? you can just echo the returned value somewhere else to check.

Comment: Okay it returned an error of `:  Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string`

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: @n.nachury I still have an error - `:  Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string`